# Установка языка (i18n) как параметра маршрута (ex.com/en/home) Quasar framework (Vue JS)

Tags: vue.js, маршрутизация, i18n, quasar-framework

Есть front где реализована мультиязычность (4-е языка). Использована библиотека i18n, смена языка происходит по нажатию на кнопку, запуск сайта осуществлялся с использованием locale: navigator.language.split('-')[0], с проверкой и выводом английского по дефолту (если нужного языка нет).
Стоит задача по добавлению названия языка в маршрут (/en/home or /ru/home). Прошу вашей помощи, как это правильно реализовать, чтобы смена языка происходила вместе с изменением url.
Взял за основу https://medium.com/hypefactors/add-i18n-and-manage-translations-of-a-vue-js-powered-website-73b4511ca69c и https://medium.com/i18n-and-l10n-resources-for-developers/the-ultimate-guide-to-vue-localization-with-vue-i18n-bf98b1d40c65, но так как у меня проект в оболочке "Quasar framework" не могу отловить ошибки, крашится роутинг между страницами.
В Quasar есть два компонента отвечающих за роутинг: router.js и index.js + ко всему в моём проекте в index.js я использую Router.beforeEach (где стоит проверка токена авторизации, чтобы разграничить маршрутизацию авторизированных и не авторизированных пользователей). Что касается добавления языка в адрес использовал router.js Вот пример моего кода:

```
const { locale } = i18n;

const routes = [{
    path: "/",
    redirect: locale
  },
  {
    path: '/:locale',
    component: () => import('layouts/MainLayout.vue'),

    beforeEnter(to, from, next){
      const lang = to.params.lang
      console.log(to);
      console.log(from);
      console.log(next);
      if(!['enUS', 'ru', 'ua', 'ge'].includes(lang)) return next('en-us');

      if(i18n.locale !== lang){
        i18n.locale = lang
      }
      return next()
    },

    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: () => import('pages/Preload.vue'),
        meta: {
          requiresAuth: false
        }
      },
      {
        path: '/auth_phone',
        component: () => import('pages/AuthPhone.vue'),
        meta: {
          requiresAuth: false} ...

     не работает и так тоже не вышло: 

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.params.locale === from.params.locale) {
     next('en')
     return
   }
   const { locale } = to.params
   next('ru')
 })
```

Comment: Весьма интересно. Мне доводилось работать с i18n на quasar, но у меня задача была чуть другая: язык брался из настроек, которые, если не ошибаюсь, хранились в куках, и прикреплялся к запросу как параметр ?lang=ru. Однако делать как у Вас ещё не доводилось...

Comment: А что вообще подразумевается под крашем? Будет ли next(locale) коректно работать, если ему передаётся в качестве маршрута только язык? Может "хвост" тоже нужно прицеплять?

Comment: Сделал "костыль" вчера, отслеживаю, что попадает в :locale, затем в файле i18n проверяю есть указанный в url (адресе сайта) язык, если есть перевожу весь сайт, если нет en-us - как дефолтный, но ищу норм вариант реализации. Как передать параметры в :locale, чтоб по умолчанию en-us сайт всегда открывался, а уже по ссылкам SEO на других языках. + я так понимаю при выборе языка баттоном нужно изменять не только сайт, но и url.

Comment: Есть мнение, что для понимания Вашей задачи нужно смотреть код проекта, запускать его и тестировать.

Comment: Данный вопрос закрыл. Случайно, не работали с Ios apk собраными cordov-ой? Нарисовалась проблемка, не могу вызвать форму конкретно в моб приложении Ios (Вопрос с кодом занёс в StackOverfloww (en) может посоветуете где искать решение).

Comment: Нет, даже и близко не знаком.